# Is it good approach to generate a large CSV report to an HTTP response immediately?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I generate a large CSV report in my Spring service. I use OpenCSV for generating. It looks like this:

```java
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(printWriter);
    
for (.....) {
    writer.writeNext(row.toArray(new String[0]));
}
```

Now I pass `HttpServletResponse response.getWriter()` to `CSVWriter` and it `CSVWriter` writes to response immediately. But I have doubts. Is this approach correct? I mean generating a report immediately to an HTTP response.

I did it because I didn't want to create a temp file on a server.

Comment: Why not if there is no other choice? If I'm not wrong, the only bottleneck here is a client that downloads the response slowly (and you might decide to detect and terminate slow connections; not sure about async servlets here) + that would not need disk space. Additionally, generating reports may be a (very) heavy operation, so you might also consider to generate a full report and store it somewhere by providing a preliminary URL to access the report later (even multiple times), then expire it and delete it (all done by a simple "access only" web service).